# set Windows 10 to single click programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I'm building a WPF where i simulate touches and clicks

Is there a way to set windows single click mode only when my WPF is working ?

**UPDATE:**

I need to be able to switch between thous two options on the start and close of the WPF

[image]

Comment: Single-click for _what_?

Comment: to Open Items(folders) with a Single-Click instead of Double-Clicking them @MickyD

Comment: That's just a setting on Windows Explorer available since Windows 98. How is this related to C# and WPF?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? Are you trying to create a touch-enabled application, or work on a tablet?

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at UWP and store apps instead? These are built for single touch operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the purpose of the wpf might be strange, it's topmost but is transparent and allow click throw and has no UI components at the point where i need to implement my simulated clicks (or touches) , is there a better approach ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos see edit please

Answer (score 1):

This is known as *web view*.   You can enable and disable it programmatically when your program starts up and exits respectively.  Note, the changes will be system-wide.

To do so, you can p-invoke that from .NET via [`SHGetSetSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762200(v=vs.85).aspx) with the [`SHELLFLAGSTATE.fDoubleClickInWebView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759785(v=vs.85).aspx) member set to `0`.

The syntax is:

```
SHGetSetSettings (LPSHELLFLAGSTATE lpsfs, DWORD dwMask, BOOL set);
```

...where in your case dwMask would be set to `SSF_DOUBLECLICKINWEBVIEW` and *set* = TRUE

The p-invoke signature should be:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern void SHGetSetSettings (ref SHELLFLAGSTATE lpsfs, uint dwMask, BOOL set);
```

`SHELLFLAGSTATE` defined as: (courtesy p-invoke.net)

```
[Flags]
enum SHELLFLAGSTATE : long
{
    fShowAllObjects = 0x00000001,
    fShowExtensions = 0x00000002,
    fNoConfirmRecycle = 0x00000004,
    fShowSysFiles = 0x00000008,
    fShowCompColor = 0x00000010,
    fDoubleClickInWebView = 0x00000020,
    fDesktopHTML = 0x00000040,
    fWin95Classic = 0x00000080,
    fDontPrettyPath = 0x00000100,
    fShowAttribCol = 0x00000200,
    fMapNetDrvBtn = 0x00000400,
    fShowInfoTip = 0x00000800,
    fHideIcons = 0x00001000,
}
```

### Tell me more:

- *"[How do I read the "Double-click to open an item (single-click to select)" setting in Folder Options?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140825-00/?p=153)"*

Comment: I've failed to implement the p-invoke , can you provide me with the needed C# code

Comment: @Ahmedna see update

Comment: That's just a Windows Explorer setting available since Windows 98. There's no reason to use P/Invoke to use it. It went out of favour abouty a decade ago, which is why Web View on the desktop doesn't work anymore. It's just a setting for Explorer now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is if he wants to do it _"only when my WPF is working"_ and there is no equivalent .NET method

Comment: The OP may mean something completely different. Windows on tablets for example doesn't require double clicks or hold-and-drag. What the OP really wants may already be available

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks but OP and I already have an understanding.   He's already made it clear he's talking about folders.

Comment: my WPF will be on top most of application and will run on desktop and on other applications , I've tried touch injection but it wont open folders unless   2 touchs are injected witch is hard to implement every time. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Ahmedna that has nothing to do with what you asked though. You are asking about Kiosk mode. When your application is topmost, you can't work with folders anyway. Unless you are trying to build a WPF application that behaves the same as a store app. None of these needs double clicking or injection, they simply use *different* controls and dialogs to select files. Perhaps you should be looking at building a UWP app?

Comment: there is no SHSetSettings , only SHGetSettings in shell32.dll @MickyD

Comment: @Ahmedna Ugh, you know I did see that when I copied and pasted it and thought it was a mistake during pasting. My bad, see edit

Comment: @MickyD almost there , right now i'm able to activate the double click ,if it was set to single click on folder option , but if i put SHGetSetSettings(ref lps, SSF_DOUBLECLICKINWEBVIEW, false); the single click is not activated , also i'm uisng the following 
        const uint SSF_DOUBLECLICKINWEBVIEW = 0x00000080;